# Javascript not executing with Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, object, initialization, global-variables

I cant get a `js` `global` to work correctly with `cordova`. When the device is ready, the `app` receives the event, and then creates a `Pool` object, which is then initialized, and should show an alert. Here is my code:

**index.js**

```
var pool = null;

var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        alert('Received Event: ' + id);
        pool = new Pool();
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

In the above, I see the `"Recieved event"` alert.

I have the `Pool` object in another file that I am including index.html like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pool.js"></script>
```

**pool.js** looks like this:

```
var Pool = function() {
  var pool = {
      initialize: function() {

          ...

          alert("pool initialized");
      },


      ...


    };

    pool.initialize();
    return pool;
};
```

Why don't I see the alert after the `Pool` object is created?

**UPDATE**

My code now looks like this:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pool.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

**index.js**

```
var pool = null;

var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        pool = new Pool();
        console.log(pool.fake_data);
        pool.initialize();
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

**pool.js**

```
function Pool() {
        this.fake_data = [{item_name: "Hammer", pic: "", available: true}, {item_name: "Screwdriver", pic: "", available: true},
                                     {item_name: "Iron", pic: "", available: true}, {item_name: "Pot", pic: "", available: true},
                                     {item_name: "Stapler", pic: "", available: true}, {item_name: "Frying pan", pic: "", available: true},
                                     {item_name: "Sugar", pic: "", available: true}, {item_name: "Tape", pic: "", available: true}],

      this.initialize = function() {
          console.log("pool initialized");
      },

      ...

      }
    };
};
```

I am using `safari` to debug and i get nothing in the console, not even the `console.log` messages that should appear. I changed the `alerts` to `console.log` and I can't see either of the messages in `safari` or `Xcode`, is there another way to debug?

Xcode console output:

```
2018-11-26 20:47:55.423048-0500 Pool[569:76165] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.5.5 is starting.
2018-11-26 20:47:55.423628-0500 Pool[569:76165] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2018-11-26 20:47:55.443524-0500 Pool[569:76165] Using UIWebView
2018-11-26 20:47:55.445229-0500 Pool[569:76165] [CDVTimer][console] 0.065923ms
2018-11-26 20:47:55.445345-0500 Pool[569:76165] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.064969ms
2018-11-26 20:47:55.446376-0500 Pool[569:76165] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 0.987053ms
2018-11-26 20:47:55.446456-0500 Pool[569:76165] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.047088ms
2018-11-26 20:47:55.463569-0500 Pool[569:76165] [CDVTimer][localstorage] 17.084002ms
2018-11-26 20:47:55.463611-0500 Pool[569:76165] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 18.489003ms
2018-11-26 20:47:55.707543-0500 Pool[569:76165] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2018-11-26 20:47:55.849767-0500 Pool[569:76165] Finished load of: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/6D499572-52BB-418B-8324-CEE8FD13911C/Pool.app/www/index.html
```

Comment: To use `new`, you need to change (and simplify) things a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/jxoa29pb/ So the problem isn't that your JS code isn't executing, it's that the syntax was bad, and the console should have told you so.

Comment: thanks, so you are saying I cant have two separate files?

Comment: Not at all. But you probably need to include `pool.js` before `index.js`. Still: if you use `new Pool()` then `Pool()` will be called as constructor function, which means it mustn't return some arbitrary var. In other words, your problem isn't cordova-related.

Comment: ok thanks ill rearrange things and give it a shot

Comment: @ChrisG I updated my question, I am still having trouble, check out my changes, thanks

Comment: You have commas instead of semicolons after your `this.x = y` statements. And if you remove stuff from your scripts, please make sure the brackets still match. We can only fix the code you post, not the code you have.

Comment: i had a bracket issue that i fixed, and i changed the commas to semicolon, just missed that, but still it isnt showing log messages in safari

Comment: nevermind, i found some more errors ill see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Caused by javascript code errors, just had to fix those (I used https://jshint.com/ to help sort things out faster.